# NSSet of elements with coordinates to array of columns/rows

Tags: arrays, swift, group-by, set, nsset

I have a `NSSet` (from `CoreData`) containing `Element` with a `column` and `row` properties (both `Int16`).
I want to efficiently convert this `NSSet` to an array of array `[[Element]]` (it would be an array of the columns and the value would be an array of rows in the columns) in a way that it handles holes in coordinates and respect order.

So for example, if I have a the following elements:

```swift
let mySet = NSSet([
    Element(column: 1, row: 1, id: 'el1'), 
    Element(column: 3, row: 0, id: 'el2),
    Element(column: 3, row: 2, id: 'el3'),
    Element(column: 6, row: 12, id: 'el4'),
    Element(column: 6, row: 6, id: 'el5),
    Element(column: 6, row: 1, id: 'el6')
]);
// I would get an array like:
let resultArray = [
  [el1],
  [el2, el3],
  [el6, el5, el4]
]
```

I tried various solution like `Dictionary(grouping: ..)`, `reduce`, etc... but can't manage to make it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't compile.

`Dictionary(grouping:by:)` is indeed a possible way.

- First cast the set to Swift `Set<Element>`
- Then group the array to a dictionary by the `column` property and get the `values`
- Finally map all items to the `id` values and sort the outer array by its first item

---

```
let resultArray = Dictionary(grouping: mySwiftSet, by: \.column)
    .values
    .map { items in
        items.map(\.id).sorted()
    }
    .sorted(by: {$0.first! < $1.first!})
```

or with `reduce(into:)`

```
let resultArray = Dictionary(grouping: mySwiftSet, by: \.column)
    .reduce(into: [[String]]()) {
        $0 += [$1.value.map(\.id).sorted()]
    }
    .sorted(by: {$0.first! < $1.first!})
```

Or you can get a nested array of `Element`, the inner array sorted by row and the outer by column.

```
let resultArray = Dictionary(grouping: mySwiftSet, by: \.column)
    .reduce(into: [[Element]]()) {
        $0 += [$1.value.sorted(by:{$0.row < $1.row} )]
    }
    .sorted(by: {$0.first!.column < $1.first!.column})
```

Comment: Shouldn’t the sort be based on the column property on the last line? I’m not sure I understand the comparator. Also shouldn’t the items be sorted by the row property?

Comment: The result is `[[el1], [el2, el3], [el4, el5, el6]]` according to the requested output

Comment: PS: Now I understand, please see the edit.